# Jaxlib 0.4.7 can't be installed or built in my OSX 10.13, Python 3.9.13

Tags: python-3.x, pip, jax

I've been trying to upgrade my jaxlib but it is impossible. Jax is fine. None of the wheels in the google repository work for me. I suppose it is because I'm using OSX 10.13?

```
RuntimeError: jaxlib is version 0.3.10, but this version of jax requires version >= 0.4.7.
```

When I attempt to install Jaxlib through pip, it throws this:

```
$ pip install --upgrade jaxlib==0.4.7 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_releases.html
Looking in links: https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_releases.html
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jaxlib==0.4.7 (from versions: 0.1.60, 0.1.63, 0.1.71, 0.1.72, 0.1.73, 0.1.74, 0.1.75, 0.1.76, 0.3.0, 0.3.2, 0.3.5, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.10)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jaxlib==0.4.7
```

I am using the latest version of pip, but also tried downgrading pip. The problem still occurs.
Please help me solve this issue.

I tried installing through pip, building my own jaxlib as the site's instructions (https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer.html) and installing through the google repositories.
I also downgraded pip, with no luck.

My objective is to have Jaxlib 0.4.7 running in my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent jaxlib releases require OSX version 10.14 or newer (see https://github.com/google/jax/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#jaxlib-0314-june-27-2022).

Your options are either to update your OSX to a more recent version, to build jaxlib yourself (this can be tricky; see [building from source](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer.html)), or to use an older jaxlib release where your OS version is supported.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was suspecting. I guess it's time to update, then, because I couldn't build my own jaxlib.